# Routing and HttpContext error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this error:

> 'HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before
>   'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.

that I found out through debugging is coming from this:

```
private void CreateControllerContext() 
{
            var routeData = 
                 RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(CurrentHttpContext);
            ControllerContext = 
                 new ControllerContext(CurrentHttpContext, routeData, this);
}
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. It's coming from the `GetRouteData`, that much I know, but I am not able to figure out how to rework this. Any thoughts?